# How to uninstall a not fully installed or removed package?

Tags: uninstall, dpkg, spotify

Alright so here is my problem, I tried installing Spotify. It wasn't going well so I decided to uninstall it. Being a complete n00b I though deleting the folder where it was installed to would solve my problem. I googled how to properly delete a package and now it wont work, at all.

```
(Reading database ... 95881 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing spotify-client ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/spotify-client.prerm: 9: cd: can't cd to /opt/spotify/spotify-client
dpkg: error processing spotify-client (--remove):
subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 2
/var/lib/dpkg/info/spotify-client.postinst: 5: cd: can't cd to /opt/spotify/spotify-client
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
spotify-client
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am more lost than I was before, please help.

Content of `/var/lib/dpkg/info/spotify-client.prerm`:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Copyright (c) 2012 Spotify AB

# We could be smart and not clean up on upgrade,
# but I worry that we'll leave old crap around
# when we change things.

cd /opt/spotify/spotify-client && ./unregister.sh
```

Comment: Post the content of `/var/lib/dpkg/info/spotify-client.prerm`

Comment: @kos here is the hastebin [link](http://hastebin.com/wirizavoto.bash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The removal is failing because the pre-removal script can't be executed with success due to the failure of the `cd` command (such directory doesn't exist anymore); comment this line in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/spotify-client.prerm` by putting a `#` at the start:

```
cd /opt/spotify/spotify-client && ./unregister.sh
```

so that it becomes like this one:

```
# cd /opt/spotify/spotify-client && ./unregister.sh
```

Comment: thank you very much! I probably should have read that error message more carefully, lesson learned.

Answer (score 1):

You could always re-install Spotify, then use the proper method to remove it.  That way, you will have all the needed files on the system again.